Claim groups is not supported in Azure Active Directory Provider
I am trying to read the groups that the user has, I have created a claim called 'groups' and added this line to several technical profiles, all of them are meant to read from AAD.
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" />

but I get the error mentioned

I have tried the to declare the claim as string or as a stringCollection, no success so far.

You can only use attributes that are in the schema.
To use "groups", it needs to be an extension attribute.

It needs to be from AAD so as said by someone else, it can't be, so I am going to add a rest call to graph to see if I can catch the value this way instead.
